# Interchanging sums gives different results (showing this given an example)

Tags: real-analysis, summation

For m, n ∈ N, define $a_{mn}$ ∈ R such that a_nn = 1 for all n, $a_{mn} = −(2^n − 1)/2^n$ whenever $n = m+1$, and $a_{mn} = 0$ for all other $m, n ∈ N$. Show that $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{mn} = 1/2$ but $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} a_{mn} = 3/2$

So far I did the following to draw a picture in my head of what is going on with the sums:

For $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{mn} = 1/2$:

$a_{11} + a_{12} + a_{13} + ...$

$a_{21} + a_{22} + a_{23} + ... $

$ a_{31} + a_{32} + a_{33} + ...$ and so on

From this I noticed that all the terms on the big diagonal are 1 and all the terms to the left from that diagonal are 0. To the right of it, they satisfy the following expression: $a_{mn} = −(2^n − 1)/2^n$. This is similar to a matrix and in this case we have n rows and m columns: $n x m$ matrix

For $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} a_{mn} = 3/2$:

I constructed a similar system:

$a_{11} + a_{21} + a_{31} + ...$

$a_{12} + a_{22} + a_{32} + ... $

$ a_{13} + a_{23} + a_{33} + ...$ and so on

In this case all the numbers to the right are 0 and to the left they are described by:$a_{mn} = −(2^n − 1)/2^n$

Unfortunately, this is everything I managed to do and I do not see how I can prove the given sums.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is your matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&\frac14-1&0&0&0&\ldots\\
0&1&\frac18-1&0&0&\ldots\\
0&0&1&\frac1{16}-1&0&\ldots\\
0&0&0&1&\frac1{32}-1&\ldots\\
0&0&0&0&1&\ldots\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots
\end{bmatrix}$$

- The row sums are $\frac14,\frac18,\frac1{16},\frac1{32},\ldots\;$: the sum of row $m$ is $\frac1{2^{m+1}}$. The sum of these row sums is?
- The column sums are $1,\frac14,\frac18\frac1{16},\frac1{32},\ldots\;$: the sum of column $n$ is $\frac1{2^n}$ when $n>1$. The sum of these column sums is?

Comment: Ohhh, I totally missed out on the fact that the terms form a geometric sequence. So, for the row sums I got that it is equal to $1$ and in the column sum - $2$. However, would not the sum of all terms be just equal to the sum of $1/2^k$ between $k=1$ and $k=\infty$?

Comment: @IVU: Your sum of row sums and sum of column sums are correct. That shows that $\sum_m\sum_na_{mn}\ne\sum_n\sum_ma_{mn}$, and *that* shows that the sum of all of the entries in the matrix depends on the order in which we add them. This is a two-dimensional analogue of a conditionally convergent series, so there is no single well-defined sum.

Comment: But then for $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{mn}$ I get $2$ instead of $1/2$ and for the other $1$ instead of $3/2$. Sorry for being slow in understanding this

Comment: @IVU: That’s correct; the two sums are indeed $2$ and $1$.

Comment: The only issue is that in the question it says that $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{mn}$ is equal to $1/2$ and the second sum - to $3/2$. And so I am not sure from where they got $1/2$ and $3/2$

Comment: @IVU: My previous comment wasn’t quite right: you should have $\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{mn}=1$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty a_{mn}=2$. And I made a mistake in the array: all of the fractions on the superdiagonal are off by a factor of $2$. Give me a moment to fix it.

Comment: @IVU: I’ve fixed the silly computational error that I made in filling out the original array. The adjusted row and column sums now have the correct totals.

Comment: Oh, yes, now I see. I should have noticed that - but thank you so much! This makes much more sense.

Comment: @IVU: You’re very welcome! Sorry about the original mistake.